# Implementing keyword search on Google App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, search, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to implement a keyword/tags search for a certain entity type in GAE's datastore:

```
class Docs(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    user = db.StringProperty()
    tags = db.StringListProperty()
```

I also wrote a very basic search function (using a fake list of tags, not the datastore values), that takes a query string and matches it to each set of tags. It ranks Docs based on how many query words match the tags. This is pretty much all I need it to do, except using the actual datastore.

I have no idea how to get the actual datastore values though. For my search function to work I need a list of all the entities in the datastore, which is impossible (?).

I also tried looking into GAE's experimental full-text search, and Relation Index Entities as a way to search the datastore without using the function I wrote. Neither was successful.

Any other ideas on how to search for entities based on tags?

Comment: The search api is probably a much better choice for implementing your requirements.  You said you investigated it and it didn't work. In what way didn't it work ?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to search lists of tags with the api. It also only handles 1000 searches/day...which is kind of small.

Comment: you can request a bigger quote - its early days for it.  As for searching tags , they could just be a text field containing all the tags.  There is a very detailed example code - http://code.google.com/p/google-app-engine-samples/source/browse/trunk/search#search%2Fproduct_search_python

Comment: if you used a StringListProperty and you start trying to match for multiple tags you will end up with very expensive queries.

Comment: from the docs - The IN operator also performs multiple queries: one for each item in the specified list, with all other filters unchanged and the IN filter replaced with an equality (=) filter. The results are merged in order of the items in the list. If a query has more than one IN filter, it is performed as multiple queries, one for each possible combination of values in the IN lists.

Comment: Well ideally it would be only one query(.fetch_all() or something) to retrieve all the data from the datastore. Or is it charged by how many entities you retrieve?

Comment: no but if you are querying for things that match 3 keywords then you are using the "IN" clause for querying string list properties.  I think you need to do some reading of the docs.

Comment: Hm, I see now that it's possible. But using the api to accomplish this seems like an oversized solution to such a simple problem. The docs are huge...it looks like it would take quite a while to build a working implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a very simple query, if you need to find all Docs with a tag "findme", it's simply:

```
num_results = 10
query = Docs.all().filter("tags in", "findme")
results = query.fetch(num_results) # get list of results
```

It's well documented:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries